# Spring Boot UserRedirectRequiredException- A redirect is required to get the users approval

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am learning OAUTH2 implementation

When i hit my client end http://localhost:8082/ui - REST end point for UI which will take me to the secure URI http://localhost:8082/secure after logging into the auth server http://localhost:8081/auth/login.
But it fails at http://localhost:8082/ui/login and give me error as

org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval

My client configuration is

OauthConfig.java

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.antMatcher("/**").
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/login**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
         /*http    
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();*/
    }
}
```

and  webconfig.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");
        registry.addViewController("/index");
        registry.addViewController("/secure");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public  static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener contextlist() 
    {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

and my application.yml is

```
 server:
  port: 8082
  servlet:
    context-path: /ui
  session: 
    cookieName: UISESSION





 spring: 
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  oauth2:
    client:

      client-id: ClientId
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize


    clientAuthenticationScheme: form



    resource: 
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/rest/hello/principal
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

Do i need to write custom oauth2ClientContextFilter for this? i already have added spring-security-oauth2 to the pom.xml. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience and by exchanging `@EnableOAuth2Sso` by `@EnableOAuth2Client` it was solved.

It seems that the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation adds an additional Security Chain Filter `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to the springSecurityFilterChain and this throws the `UserRedirectRequiredException`.

Answer (score 0):

Update SecurityContextHolder

SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);