# Spring Security 5 Google OAuth2 Error - A redirect is required to get the users approval (UserRedirectRequiredException)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social-google

I am trying to implement Spring security using google's oauth server.
Application is very simple.

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.property has oauth configuration :

```
security.oauth2.client.id=xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=XXYYXXX
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
security.oauth2.client.token-name=oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=query
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form
security.oauth2.client.scope=profile email

security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info=false
```

Then implemented basic websecurity :

```
package com.example.blog;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

index.html file is very basic :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="user"> Google Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Main application class :

```
package com.example.blog;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class GoogleOAuthLogin4Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GoogleOAuthLogin4Application.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Principal get(Principal p)
    {
        return p;
    }
}
```

After starting the server, when I hit http://localhost:8080 it loads index.html. When I click the link it shows following error page :

[image]

Server logs are as follows : 
UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval

```
2018-07-24 23:15:01.174 ERROR 13452 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:359) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:205) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

I spent lot of time and tried to find the solution but i did not succeeded.
But I found similar unanswered issues here :

1) [Spring Security Facebook Oauth2 redirected too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191132/spring-security-facebook-oauth2-redirected-too-many-times)
2) [Spring Boot UserRedirectRequiredException- A redirect is required to get the users approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073124/spring-boot-userredirectrequiredexception-a-redirect-is-required-to-get-the-use)

So I believe that lot of people are facing same issue.
It would be of great help to me and many others if you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you working behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I am not working behind a proxy. I have tried this from two different places.

Comment: So as I understand you issue, the exchange of authorization_code for the access_token is not working. Please doublecheck following params: clientId, clientSecret, userAuthorizationUri

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your application.properties file code for Oauth2

Use below properties same as here means copy and paste in your application properties file and put your client id and secret key ,so it will work fine..try once

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId= ****Your ClientId **********************
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret= ****Your Secret ********************
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri  =  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri  =  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
security.oauth2.client.tokenName = oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme = query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme = form
security.oauth2.client.scope = profile email
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri  =  https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo = false
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following application.properties file it was working for me:

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=xxxxx
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=xxxxx
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
security.oauth2.client.tokenName=oauth_token
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme=query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
security.oauth2.client.scope=email profile
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=false




@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public Principal user(Principal p)
{
    return p;
}
```

Comment: In your properties file, there are few version changes. I will change my property file according to it and will let you know.Thanks.

Comment: I tried but it is getting same exception mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see that there are no redirect URI specified when the "google link" in the html/jsp page is clicked.

Can you specify the properties with the authorization server to which the flow should be redirected to. I haven't tried with google/facebook but we use a thirdparty authorization which worked. We had a endpoint uri with the redirection takes place - /v1 and not a link.

Also there is no real reason to implement the user details service if your auth server can act as the resource server as well.

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=XXXXX
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=XXXXXX
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid+profile+email
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://XXXXXX/oidctoken.aspx
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://XXXXX/secureauth.aspx
security.oauth2.client.grant-type=authorization_code
security.oauth2.client.resource-ids=code
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://localhost:8081/XXX/login
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://localhost:8081/XXX/login
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://localhost:8081/XXXX/user
###--------Spring oauth2 security configuration ends-----------#
##
###--------Initial url-----------#
#security.oauth2.sso.login-path = /v1
```

Answer (score 1):

`security.oauth2.client.id=xxxxx` should be `security.oauth2.client.clientId=xxxxx`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it with this:

Eclipse -> Build Path -> Configure -> Source -> Excluded -> Remove (None)